# WKScriptMessageHandlerWithReply delegate methods are called on non-main thread

Tags: swift, async-await, wkwebview, wkscriptmessage

I'm using `WKScriptMessageHandlerWithReply` to receive messages from a `WKWebView`.

I recently refactored the code to separate view related code and logic related code into a `WebViewController`/`WebController`.

```
class WebController: NSObject {
    func performSomeAction() async -> (Any?, String?) {
        // ...
    }
}

extension WebController: WKScriptMessageHandlerWithReply {
    func userContentController(_: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) async -> (Any?, String?) {
        guard message.name == MESSAGE_HANDLER_NAME else {
            return
        }

        if message.body == "some_event_name" {
            return async performSomeAction()
        }

        return (nil, "unknown event")
    }
}
```

Since this refactor the method is still called just fine, but no longer on the main thread. But the properties of `WKScriptMessage` have to be accessed only the main thread:

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[WKScriptMessage name]
```

Why did this behavior change? And what's a good way to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate methods of `WKScriptMessageHandlerWithReply` are called on the main thread by default when the receiver is a subclass of `UIResponder`, which also included `UIViewController`.

But with the new setup the `WebController` is a subclass of `NSObject` which results in the delegate method being called on random threads.

To ensure the delegate method is called on the main thread, you can annotate the method with `@MainActor`.

```
extension WebController: WKScriptMessageHandlerWithReply {
    @MainActor
    func userContentController(_: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) async -> (Any?, String?) {
        guard message.name == MESSAGE_HANDLER_NAME else {
            return
        }

        if message.body == "some_event_name" {
            return async performSomeAction()
        }

        return (nil, "unknown event")
    }
}
```